# Combination Book Problem

Tags: combinations

I need a help in Combination

*Question*:

> In how many ways can $21$ identical Physics books and $19$ identical Chemistry Books to be arranged in row on a shelf, so that two chemistry books may not be together?

Comment: no idea on this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First place all the $21$ Physics books in a row.

Then there are $22$ places to place the chemistry books, but we have to place only $19$ books.

So, the no. of way is $${22\choose 19}={22\choose 3}$$

Comment: @Balla, Did you got this, or I have to explain a bit more.

Comment: i have got it and answer also correct Very Thank you